# Magento2.4.3 admin customer grid sorting not working after click on customer id field

Tags: magento2.4.3

In magento admin, Open customer grid and sort customer id field. Every time data shows in
ascending order.

Comment: click on column header sorting will change on every click .explain little bit more what you want to do?

Comment: Customer grid sorting not working when click on Id field. Its shows data in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click on ID section to set ascending and descending order.